# findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition returns -1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have following code :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Integer> data = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            data.add(i);
        }

        MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(data);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        RecyclerView list = findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        if (layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == adapter.getItemCount() - 1) {

        }
    }
```

`findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` returns -1. What is the reason of that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are trying to get last visible item during `onCreate`.

During `onCreate`, No `View` was measured/positioned yet. So, it is impossible to get that information right at `onCreate`

**Edit**

You can add a layout listener to be invoked after the `RecyclerView` is measured.
Something like:

```
recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(final View v, final int left,
                                   final int top,
                                   final int right,
                                   final int bottom,
                                   final int oldLeft,
                                   final int oldTop,
                                   final int oldRight,
                                   final int oldBottom) {
            int lastVisibleItem = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if(lastVisibleItem > 0 && adapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
                Log.d("TEST", "LastItem: " + lastVisibleItem);

                // You can call this after you get your information to remove the listener
                // This way, it won't be called everytime there's a re-layout
                //recyclerView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: In which callback method I can call it?

Comment: Do you need that info as soon as the views are inflated or just when user click in a view or perform some action?

Comment: Yes if possible I need it as soon as view inflated.

Comment: I update the answer. Check if it helps... I suggest to add some logs on the onLayoutChange method. This way, you can check thru logs if that method is not being called indefinitely... This can happen if during onLayoutChange you apply a new change which will trigger a new layout change etc...

Comment: you can either try the following:
recyclerView.post(new Runnable { int position = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition(); ... })